# About the Level of Non-Abelian Chern Simon theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, chern-simons-theory

The Lagrangian of the non-Abelian Chern Simons theory is the following
$$\mathcal{L}=\frac{k}{4\pi}\int \text{tr}(AdA+\frac{2}{3}AAA)$$
What is the definition of tr here? Namely, which representation should we choose to calculate the trace? What if we choose other representations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing the $\mathcal{L}$ with indices,

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L} = \frac{k}{4\pi} \int \epsilon^{\mu\nu\rho} \operatorname{tr}\Big(A_{\mu}\partial_{\nu}A_{\rho} + \frac{2}{3}A_{\mu}A_{\nu}A_{\rho}\Big) 
\end{equation}

The trace ($\mathrm{tr}$) here is usually assumed in the defining (see below) representation. Sometimes, $\mathrm{Tr}$ is used to denote the trace when the A's i.e $A_{\mu}^{a} T_{a}$ are expanded where $T_{a}$ are in the adjoint representation (then $T_{a}$ are of size $N_{G} \times N_{G}$, where $N_{G}$ is the number of generators of the gauge group).

In representations for ex. for  $SU(N)$ as $p \times p$ matrices, there are three possible representations once can consider for $p$.

- $p=1$:     trivial representation
- $p=N$:     defining (a.k.a fundamental) representation
- $p=N^2-1$: adjoint representation

One usually won't take the traces in adjoint representations, because of its size, however, there does exist relations that connect the fundamental rep. trace to adjoint ones (I know string theory books discuss this). A  useful (maybe) reference is: http://scipp.ucsc.edu/~haber/ph218/sunid17 
(If this is not working, see detailed description in the comment)

Comment: To prevent link rot, it's better to mention author and title explicitly (so that the link can be reconstructed in case of need). In this case, these are lecture notes for the course *Advanced Quantum Field Theory* (2016),  University of California, Santa Cruz, by Howard Haber. The file is entitled *Useful relations involving the generators of SU(N)*. The course webpage is http://scipp.ucsc.edu/~haber/ph218/